# Correlation Coefficient in MATLAB with variable names

Tags: matlab, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient between variables in MATLAB. I have a matrix called M, in which each column represents a variable. This is the function I'm using:

> A = corrcoef(M,"Rows","complete")

I am getting a table of correlation coefficients, but not the variable names. For instance, I cannot directly see what the 3rd column in A represents - I'd have to go and check M to see the ordering of the variables along the columns.

How do I display the variable names in the correlation table?

Note: I converted M to a table and added variable headers, but the correlation table does not show the variable names.

Comment: Why don't you create a table from your array `A`, and then add the row and column headers from the headers in `M`? you can add [row and column headers at the same time if you want](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/340496-add-column-and-row-labels-to-matrix)

Comment: Yes - that worked. Thank you!
How do I accept your answer?

Comment: It was a comment so you cannot accept it. But you can write an answer yourself and accept it so that other users needing it can use it. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BillBokeey suggested in the comments, a solution is to create a table from the array A, and then add the row and column headers I had previously created for M.